# Second flatlist overlaps the first flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I wrote a code in `ScrollView` where i had to show 2 `view` components:-

```
<ScrollView 
    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnable} 
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref} 
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { 
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }); }} 
>
            <View pointerEvents="none">
                {this.state.TempView}
            </View>
            <View>
                {this.state.MainScrollView}
            </View>
</ScrollView >
```

I wished to use it with `FlatList`, so I did it like this:-

```
<FlatList
    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnable}
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { 
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }); }}
        data={this.state.TempView}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>{item}</View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
<FlatList
    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnable}
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { 
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }); }}
        data={this.state.MainScrollView}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>{item}</View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

But the second `FlatList` data is present over the first one....
resulting in data of both the `FlatList` being shown at the same screen.
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it...
I set the data of the first FlatList in the `ListHeaderComponent` prop of the `FlatList`. The result code is:-

```
<FlatList
    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnable}
    style={s}
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { 
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }); }}
    ListHeaderComponent={<View>{this.state.TempView}</View>}
    data={this.state.MainScrollView}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>{item}</View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```